# Amazon Web service - signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, hash, encode, signature

I've been receiving an error from Amazon web service

> InvalidParameterValue
> Either Action or Operation query parameter must be present.

I believe it is most likely due to the signature being incorrect as the XML document and Header matches that of a test I did in their scratchpad.

Does anything stand out as being incorrect?

```
private static string ConstructCanonicalQueryString(SortedDictionary<string, string> sortedParameters)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    if (sortedParameters.Count == 0)
    {
        builder.Append(string.Empty);
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    foreach (var kvp in sortedParameters)
    {
        builder.Append(PercentEncodeRfc3986(kvp.Key));
        builder.Append("=");
        builder.Append(PercentEncodeRfc3986(kvp.Value));
        builder.Append("&");
    }

    var canonicalString = builder.ToString();
    return canonicalString.Substring(0, canonicalString.Length - 1);
}


private static string PercentEncodeRfc3986(string value)
{
    value = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? string.Empty : value, Encoding.UTF8);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    value = value.Replace("'", "%27")
            .Replace("(", "%28")
            .Replace(")", "%29")
            .Replace("*", "%2A")
            .Replace("!", "%21")
            .Replace("%7e", "~")
            .Replace("+", "%20")
            .Replace(":", "%3A");

    var sbuilder = new StringBuilder(value);

    for (var i = 0; i < sbuilder.Length; i++)
    {
        if (sbuilder[i] != '%')
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (!char.IsLetter(sbuilder[i + 1]) && !char.IsLetter(sbuilder[i + 2]))
        {
            continue;
        }

        sbuilder[i + 1] = char.ToUpper(sbuilder[i + 1]);
        sbuilder[i + 2] = char.ToUpper(sbuilder[i + 2]);
    }

    return sbuilder.ToString();
}

public string SignRequest(Dictionary<string, string> parametersUrl, Dictionary<string, string> 

parametersSignture)
{
    var secret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parametersSignture["Secret"]);
    var signer = new HMACSHA256(secret);

    var pc = new ParamComparer();
    var sortedParameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(parametersUrl, pc);
    var orderedParameters = ConstructCanonicalQueryString(sortedParameters);
         
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(parametersSignture["RequestMethod"])
            .Append(" \n")
            .Append(parametersSignture["EndPoint"])
            .Append("\n")
            .Append("/\n")
            .Append(orderedParameters);

    var stringToSign = builder.ToString();
    var toSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);

    var sigBytes = signer.ComputeHash(toSign);
    var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(sigBytes);

    return signature.Replace("=", "%3D").Replace("/", "%2F").Replace("+", "%2B");
}

public class ParamComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string p1, string p2)
    {
        return string.CompareOrdinal(p1, p2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please reduce a bit the size of the code, showing only the most relevant part, and post the error message too?

Comment: The signature helper uses all code above, the issue could be within any of the sub methods, will it be helpful to remove it? The error message is on the first line or the post and looks like a generic error. When I googled this the only thing close to it was talking about the signature.

Comment: I have reduced it as much as possible :-)

Comment: the error tells you what is wrong: "InvalidParameterValue Either Action or Operation query parameter must be present." You need to specify an operation that you're performing.

Comment: Weirdly the Action is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the Action wasn't included correctly into the Request